# a function that exhibits wrong values only when a specific value for an argument is inserted

Tags: r, function, data-science

I'm working on a data set that shows mortality rate for certain diseases and other info in hospitals in various states, and here it is.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1FTZJQLdw0PKw2bQ7XvxWnOITU7-yOCXC

I'm trying to write a function called rankall() that takes TWO (2) arguments: (a) the disease (output) which might be one of three: heart attack, heart failure, pneumonia; and (b) a hospital ranking (num). The function reads the dataset and returns a TWO(2)-column data frame containing the hospital in EACH state that has the ranking specified in num. For example the function call

```
rankall(“heart attack”, “best”)
```

would return a data frame containing the names of the hospitals that are the best in their respective states for THIRTY(30)-day heart attack death rates. The function should return a value for EVERY state (some may be NA). The FIRST (1st) column in the data frame is named hospital, which contains the hospital name, and the SECOND (2nd) column is named state, which contains the TWO(2)-character abbreviation for the state name. The function should use the following template.

i've written the function and it works perfectly fine if the output argument is heart attack or heart failure, but when the output is pneumonia it gives wrong values.
and here is my code:

```
 rankall <- function(outcome, num = "best"){
  outcome1 <- read.csv("outcome-of-care-measures.csv")
  if (!outcome %in% c("heart attack", "heart failure", "pneumonia")){
    stop("invalid outcome")
  }
  if (outcome == "heart attack"){
    column <- 11
  }
  else if (outcome == "heart failure"){
    column <- 17
  }
  else{
    column <- 23
  }
  vec <- unique(outcome1[,7])
  x <- vector()
  for (i in vec){
    outcome2 <- subset(outcome1, State == i)
    outcome2[,column] <- as.numeric(outcome2[,column])
    outcome3 <- outcome2[order(outcome2[,column], outcome2[,2]),]
    outcome3 <- outcome3[(!is.na(outcome3[,column])),]
    if (num == "best"){
      num <- 1
      }
    else if (num == "worst"){
      num <- nrow(outcome3)
    }
    ans <- outcome3[num,2]
    x <- c(x, ans)
  }
  df <- data.frame(hospitals =x, state = vec)
  final <- df[order(df[,2]),]
  final
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to get the ranking of hospitals for these outcome, by state. I cannot replicate the problems you are seeing. I also don't think your function is working for the non-pneu outcomes the way you really want it to work. You can wrap this in a function if necessary, although there are even simpler ways to do it. If you do want a function with the structure you have above, here are a couple of ways to do it (Unless necessary, I don't think you need/want to have the `read` calls inside the function, although I've left them in, as you have).

```
library(data.table)
rankall <- function(outcome, num=c("best", "worst")) {
  num=match.arg(num)
  outc = list(
    "heart attack" = "Hospital 30-Day Death (Mortality) Rates from Heart Attack",
    "heart failure" = "Hospital 30-Day Death (Mortality) Rates from Heart Failure",
    "pneumonia" = "Hospital 30-Day Death (Mortality) Rates from Pneumonia")[[outcome]]
  dat = fread("outcome.csv")[, out:=as.numeric(get(outc))][!is.na(out)]
  
  if(num=="worst") dat[,out:=-1*out]
  dat[order(out), .SD[1], by=State, .SDcols=c("Hospital Name",outc)][order(State)]
}
```

If you prefer using tidyverse

```
library(tidyverse)
rankall <- function(outcome, num=c("best", "worst")) {
  num=match.arg(num)
  outc = list(
    "heart attack" = "Hospital 30-Day Death (Mortality) Rates from Heart Attack",
    "heart failure" = "Hospital 30-Day Death (Mortality) Rates from Heart Failure",
    "pneumonia" = "Hospital 30-Day Death (Mortality) Rates from Pneumonia")[[outcome]]
  dat = read_csv("outcome.csv",progress = F,show_col_types = F) %>% 
    mutate(out = as.numeric(get(outc))) %>% 
    filter(!is.na(out))
  
  if(num=="worst") dat <- dat %>% mutate(out = out*-1)
  dat %>% arrange(out) %>% group_by(State) %>% slice_min(out) %>% select(State,`Hospital Name`)
}
```

Updated - here is another approach that gives you the rankings for all types

```
library("data.table")
out = fread("outcome.csv")[,c(7,2,11,17,23)]
setnames(out, c("state", "hosp", "attack", "failure", "pneu"))
out = melt(out, id=c("state","hosp"))
out[,value:=as.numeric(fifelse(value=="Not Available", "",value))]
out = out[!is.na(value)][order(state,variable,value)][,.SD[c(1,.N)], by=.(state,variable)]
out[, type:=rep(c("best", "worst"),times=nrow(out)/2)]
out = dcast(out, state+variable~type,value.var = c("hosp","value"))[
  , .(state,outcome=variable, hosp_best, rate_best=value_best, hosp_worst, rate_worst=value_worst)]
```

Output

```
      state outcome                          hosp_best rate_best                       hosp_worst rate_worst
     <char>  <fctr>                             <char>     <num>                           <char>      <num>
  1:     AK  attack   PROVIDENCE ALASKA MEDICAL CENTER      13.4   MAT-SU REGIONAL MEDICAL CENTER       17.7
  2:     AK failure           SOUTH PENINSULA HOSPITAL      10.8      FAIRBANKS MEMORIAL HOSPITAL       15.6
  3:     AK    pneu YUKON KUSKOKWIM DELTA REG HOSPITAL       9.7 CORDOVA COMMUNITY MEDICAL CENTER      200.0
  4:     AL  attack           CRESTWOOD MEDICAL CENTER      13.3   HELEN KELLER MEMORIAL HOSPITAL       19.6
  5:     AL failure GEORGE H. LANIER MEMORIAL HOSPITAL       8.8   DEKALB REGIONAL MEDICAL CENTER       16.6
 ---                                                                                                        
158:     WV failure          FAIRMONT GENERAL HOSPITAL       9.5       OHIO VALLEY MEDICAL CENTER       14.3
159:     WV    pneu             WEIRTON MEDICAL CENTER       9.0           PLATEAU MEDICAL CENTER       16.2
160:     WY  attack             WYOMING MEDICAL CENTER      14.9       SHERIDAN MEMORIAL HOSPITAL       18.3
161:     WY failure         CHEYENNE VA MEDICAL CENTER      10.3           WYOMING MEDICAL CENTER       14.3
162:     WY    pneu         CHEYENNE VA MEDICAL CENTER       9.5 NORTH BIG HORN HOSPITAL DISTRICT       17.3
```

Comment: The problem is that the function that i've written is actually working for non-pneu values. This is an assignment for a course and they give you examples with answers to try your function and they are all correct, also there is a quiz with other values and i got them all correct, so all works fine except for the non-pneu and i dont understand why. Regarding your functions, i can't quite get the difference between your answer and mine, but maybe because i'm still new to R and i'm not familiar with some of the functions you used

Comment: Hi there, Since you haven't shown us what the problem is with the pneu outcome (except to say that it is not working, there is not much I can do to help). However, I've given you another approach, that you can use to test your results.

Comment: @Omarelshazly, which is the worst performing hospital in Wisconsin with respect to Heart Failure?  `rankall("heart failure", "worst")` appears to return "HOLY FAMILY MEMORIAL INC`.  Is that correct?

Comment: Yes it returns HOLY FAMILY MEMORIAL you're right. Regarding the problem with the pneu outcome, it just returns wrong rankings, so for example if i want the worst hospitals in all states, it will return wrong hospital names that aren't the worse

Comment: Btw a mentor in the course told me what the problem is but i still didn't quite get it, it seems to be in the if num == worst, but i'm not quite convinced because the function returns wrong rankings for pneu outcome whatever the ranking was (even if it's "worst). I will show you his answer anyway.

Comment: The answer: You are pretty close, but when num is "worst" your code is redefining num to be the appropriate value for the first entry  in vec defined by vec <- unique(outcome1[,7]). That value won't be the correct value for (most of) the following states / territories. When num is "worst" you need to define another variable containing the appropriate rank for the "current" state within the for loop and use that row number to get the hospital for that state. In general it is good practice not to redefine an argument of a function within the function to avoid this type of issue.

Comment: The ans(contd.): Also, a suggestion - it is best to look over any data set one is using and see if the data set uses something other than NA to indicate missing data (NA) (and in other circumstances such as statistical analysis, look for outliers etc.). Then use the na.strings option in read.csv (see the options listed for read.table) to "tell" R to interpret any such string(s)  as NA,  for example, 
na.strings = c("NA", "data not available", "sample dropped on floor") 
(the default is "NA" so if no other indicator other than NA entries is used to indicate missing data)

Comment: Part 3: Also, since we are not using factor data for this assignment, it is helpful to use the option

stringsAsFactors = FALSE

Then read.csv will read in the numeric columns as numeric and the character columns as character (not factor) data. For certain statistical procedures one might want some character columns read in as factor data (if need be for some data set one could use the colClasses option to specifiy how each column is read in).

Comment: Edit: he was right regarding the problem with "worst" only i made a mistake in the above comment saying it gives wrong values for other rankings, since i tried other rankings than "worst" in pneu and it gave correct values, but i still can't figure why what i wrote in the code was wrong

Answer (score 0):

The following function seems to work.

**Note** that the function has an extra argument, `X`, the data set.
It uses `split` instead of `unique` to divide the data by states and then applies a `lapply` loop to this list.

```
rankall <- function(X, outcome, num = "best"){
  if (!outcome %in% c("heart attack", "heart failure", "pneumonia")){
    stop("invalid outcome")
  }
  if (outcome == "heart attack"){
    column <- 11
  }
  else if (outcome == "heart failure"){
    column <- 17
  }
  else{
    column <- 23
  }
  
  i_FUN <- (1:2)[1L + (num == "worst")]
  FUN <- list(which.min, which.max)[[i_FUN]]
  sp <- split(X[c(2, column)], X[["State"]])
  
  out <- lapply(seq_along(sp), function(i){
    State <- names(sp)[i]
    if(nrow(sp[[i]]) == 0L) {
      data.frame(hospitals = NA_character_, state = State)
    } else {
      Rank <- suppressWarnings(as.numeric(sp[[i]][[2]]))
      if(all(is.na(Rank))) {
        data.frame(hospitals = NA_character_, state = State)
      } else {
        r <- FUN(Rank)
        hospital <- sp[[i]][r, "Hospital.Name", drop = TRUE]
        data.frame(hospitals = hospital, state = State)
      }
    }
  })
  final <- do.call(rbind, out)
  row.names(final) <- NULL
  final
}
```